# A View for Referenced and Referencing Nodes

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I am working on an employee directory, with the data being imported from Active Directory.  I am creating profile content nodes, and using a node reference field to indicate who the employee's manager is.

I can create a view that will show me the emplyoee's manager, and information from the manager's node (through a relationship), but I do not seem to understand how to make a view that will display a manager's employee's.

Help, pointers, doc's or examples are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use [Reverse Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference).

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that question when I was posting and looking at the related questions.  Thanks - noted that there are several solutions in that other question's response.